# form array of array checkboxes

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I want to make an array that contains several arrays that store results of checkboxes.

```
category->subcategory->choice
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I want something like this maybe:

```
<input type="hidden" name="category[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat1[]" value="something" />
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat1[]" value="somewhere" />
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat2[]" value="something" />
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat2[]" value="somewhere" />
```

I want to be able to take the category array loop through it with PHP like this:

```
foreach($_POST['category'] as $sub){
    switch($sub){
        case 'subcat1':
            foreach($sub as $val){
                //prepare $val to insert into database X
            }
            break;
        case 'subcat2':
            foreach($sub as $val){
                //prepare $val to insert into database Y
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is possible but what is specifically your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even easier than you think:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[subcat1][]" value="something" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[subcat1][]" value="somewhere" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[subcat2][]" value="something" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[subcat2][]" value="somewhere" />
```

And then:

```
foreach($_POST['category'] as $subCategoryName) {
    foreach ($subCategoryName as $item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If your intended treatment for different subcategories is not similar though, it would be better if you just posted them to different arrays.

Comment: I figured it would be less code if I used a 2D array then use a switch, may just do that though.